# coloring row's background based on custom field value

Tags: custom-post-types, filters

i am using acf , in admin dashborad i have post type called Requests , i want to set background color based on column value called status , like

if the status is approved the row should be green 
if the status is rejected the row should be grey

[image]

Comment: Have you looked into the status row classes in the html? Or is this a custom status?

Comment: custom status by custom filed

Answer (score 0):

```
function add_custom_status_class( $classes, $class, $post_id ) {
    if ( 'request' === get_post_type( $post_id ) ) {
        $status = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'hrs_field_status', true );
        if ( $status === 'accepted' ) {
            $classes[] = 'status-accepted';
        } elseif ( $status === 'rejected' ) {
            $classes[] = 'status-rejected';
        }
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'post_class', 'add_custom_status_class', 10, 3 );


function custom_admin_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-admin-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom-admin.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_admin_css', 999 );
```

Comment: and then you can add css code in the i called (custom-admin.css)